# Can't access object members javascript after getting info from mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

The query to the database returns the correct object but I'm having trouble accessing the values of the members of the object.

Here's my code:

```
socket.on("getUser", function(username){
    User.find({username: username}, function (err, user)
    {
        console.log("*** " + user + " \n*** " + typeof user);
        console.log(user.username);

        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            socket.emit("getUserResponse", user);
        }
    })
});
```

The output from this is:

```
*** { ticketsPurchased: [],
  _id: 5add436fb3da1931c8a64de6,
  username: 'nekumes@emailure.net',
  password: 'test',
  firstName: 'abc',
  lastName: 'abd',
  admin: false,
  __v: 0 } 
*** Type = object
*** undefined
```

Why can't I access the value of username? It works fine when I output the user object.  Please help!

Comment: This can be an issue where the variable is a string, you may have to parse it before accessing the variables inside it. 

Parse the data with JSON.parse(), and the data becomes a JavaScript object.

Example - const userJson = JSON.parse(user);

Try this out

Comment: Also remember that `.find()` returns an "array". If you expect **one** result then you really want `findOne()` or `console.log(user[0].username)`